# MYSQL Create Event Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, events

I am trying to find the syntax to execute a stored procedure once a day around 11pm.  This is what I current have:

```
CREATE EVENT e_call_myproc
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    DO CALL upd_override("202006", "MH");
```

How to I specify the time to execute?

Comment: Hi Mike, 1 thing you may want to include in a post is what version of MySQL you are using.  MySQL is notorious for having drastic differences between versions.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a scheduled event like so :
STARTS and ENDS are optional

```
CREATE EVENT e_call_myproc
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS [enddate]
```